# Xamarin.Android: The specified task executable "java.exe" could not be run. The filename or extension is too long

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I got error while building Xamarin.Android project with **Visual Studio Preview 15.5.0 Preview 1.0**. This happened right after i updated my visual studio preview to the latest version. I have no code error.

### The specified task executable "java.exe" could not be run. The filename or extension is too long

Visual studio window output:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Preview\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2092,3):
>   warning MSB6002: The command-line for the "CompileToDalvik" task is
>   too long. Command-lines longer than 32000 characters are likely to
>   fail. Try reducing the length of the command-line by breaking down the
>   call to "CompileToDalvik" into multiple calls with fewer parameters
>   per call.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Preview\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2092,3):
>   error MSB6003: The specified task executable "java.exe" could not be
>   run. The filename or extension is too long

Update: By the way I've modified csproj file to have output files in root folder of the drive. What I've done is; editing android project's csproj file like below but didn't help.

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>True</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
        <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
        <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86</AndroidSupportedAbis>
====>>       
        <UseShortFileNames>True</UseShortFileNames>
        <OutputPath>C:\X\Droid\bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <IntermediateOutputPath>C:\X\Droid\obj\Debug\</IntermediateOutputPath>
<<====
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I found this but no solution => https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59651&GoAheadAndLogIn=1

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, it will be fixed in next preview (hopefully it's coming soon):
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59651

As far as I know there is no workaround.